# download images with json url in android

Tags: android, json, image, android-recyclerview, download

How can I download these url images with json?

This is my image URL and I want to download and display these images. How can I recyclerview? What is my pattern? How do I download images step-by-step? I saved these links in mysql db and I showed them with json as follows. I hope I've been able to express my meaning and I'm sorry for the English.

This is my  json code:

```
{
  "images url": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "url": "http://mehrsoftshop.ir/images/mobile-1.jpg",
      "discount_code": "0",
      "price": "0",
      "details": "",
      "points": "0",
      "is_found": "0"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "url": "http://mehrsoftshop.ir/images/mobile-2.jpg",
      "discount_code": "0",
      "price": "0",
      "details": "",
      "points": "0",
      "is_found": "0"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "url": "http://mehrsoftshop.ir/images/mobile-3.jpg",
      "discount_code": "0",
      "price": "0",
      "details": "",
      "points": "0",
      "is_found": "0"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "url": "http://mehrsoftshop.ir/images/mobile-4.jpg",
      "discount_code": "0",
      "price": "0",
      "details": "",
      "points": "0",
      "is_found": "0"
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "url": "http://mehrsoftshop.ir/images/mobile-5.jpg",
      "discount_code": "0",
      "price": "0",
      "details": "",
      "points": "0",
      "is_found": "0"
    },
    {
      "id": "6",
      "url": "http://mehrsoftshop.ir/images/mobile-6.jpg",
      "discount_code": "0",
      "price": "0",
      "details": "",
      "points": "0",
      "is_found": "0"
    },
    {
      "id": "7",
      "url": "http://mehrsoftshop.ir/images/mobile-7.jpg",
      "discount_code": "0",
      "price": "0",
      "details": "",
      "points": "0",
      "is_found": "0"
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: do you know how to parse json? if so, there is a library called picasso. http://square.github.io/picasso/ works great.... if you need help with the recylcer view, i would recommend looking at tutorials nad getting help that way. at the end of the day, stackoverflow is here to help you with CODE. not with providing the overall solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use either Glide and Picasso to load images into activity.

```
Glide.with(context).load("url").into(imageView);
```

Use Retrofit or Asynctask to parse JSON. Create a Recycler view and in onBindViewHolder method of Adapter class, try this code.
For more reference, Checkout this repository.
[Click here](https://github.com/afreakyelf/yulu_)